# He performs better "from the desk" - What's the better way of putting it?

Tags: phrase-request

> He performs better **from the desk** than at the blackboard.

I am afraid that in the sentence above the words "from the desk" may be understood as if the student were performing while standing on the desk; however, what I want to express is the idea that he was sitting at the desk. I don't know what words I should use to convey the desired meaning more precisely instead of "from the desk".

1. "from behind the desk"?
2. "from his desk place"?
3. "from at the desk"?
4. ?

Comment: Perhaps "He performs better seated."

Comment: I might use "at his desk".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

> He performs better seated at his desk than at the blackboard.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that I could put it that way.